# Mobile iPhone and Android - Highlight when using bluetooth keyboard on calendar display outside of frame

Tags: android, ios, keyboard

When using the bluetooth keyboard and tabbing through a calendar control, part of the highlight around the previous/next month is out of the calendar control.

Has anyone experienced the same? Was there a solution?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s off topic for this site